# Memória ocupada do ImageView

Tags: java, android, memória, imageview

Tenho uma *activity* com *background* com uma `ImageView` de 480x800. Se eu dividir esta imagem em 4 partes iguais (240x400) e colocar na mesma *activity* as 4 novas imagens, lado a lado de modo que faça o mesmo visual da grande, vou ocupar menos memoria no celular, ou dá no mesmo? Pelo menos o `apk` vai diminuir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `apk` irá diminuir, mas não fará diferença quando você multiplicar a imagem na memória, o espaço ocupado será o que efetivamente é usado e não o original, então terá um pequeno ganho porque o executável na memória será menor, mas não o uso efetivo.

Na verdade tem outros fatores que farão muito mais diferença e provavelmente essa tentativa de economia não ajudará muito. Entender o funcionamento geral da memória, como os objetos são alocados e liberados podem dar um resultado mais efetivo.

Comment: Maniero, entendi... Na verdade no fim dá no mesmo... Vou depois estudar os objetos alocados e liberados na memoria. Vlw...

Comment: > "Pelo menos o APK vai diminuir", dê uma olhada nisto se estiver interessado https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size#compress

Comment: Não sei porque alteraram o titulo desta pergunta. Pelo titulo que ficou agora, até parece que eu quero ensinar e não aprender... Puxa Maniero, que dica excelente. Eu nem sabia que existia isso. Vlw...